# Showing multiple ranges in Clang DiagnosticBuilder

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

In a clang-tidy check I am writing, I want to show multiple ranges. And there is

```
inline const DiagnosticBuilder &operator<<(const DiagnosticBuilder &DB,
                                           ArrayRef<SourceRange> Ranges)
```

which seems to be exactly what I need. So I tried

```
SmallVector<SourceRange, 4> RangesToShow = ...;
auto Diag = diag(RangesToShow[0].getBegin(), AMessage) << RangesToShow;
```

and verified that in the test case `RangesToShow.size()` is 2, but instead of the desired

```
<range1>  <range2>
^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
```

I see

```
<range1>  <range2>
^
```